# Sticky first column on table

Tags: html, css, angular

I have the following table https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-wave-uo7dow?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

I can't seem to make the first column to be sticky when scrolling ( I want to always be visible when horizontally scrolling), I tried absolutely position also but the second column goes underneath the first one.

Is there something that I am missing? Such as the td tag cannot be set sticky or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the structure of your HTML? The selectors you are applying in your CSS do not match the elements on the page.

On line 58 you are targeting `table thead th:first-child` but you do not have a `<thead>` or a `<th>` in your html.

```
table thead th:first-child {
   position: sticky;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 2;
}
```

Should be:

```
table tr td:first-child {
   position: sticky;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 2;
}
```